# Remove extra table from web scraping results in python

Tags: python, web, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

My code produces extra tables that i'd like to remove. I want to remove all other tables except for this one.

**My Code**

```
import csv 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd 
import telnetlib as tn
import os 
#import sys 
cwd = os.getcwd()
print (os.getcwd)
cwd = os.getcwd()
os.chdir('c:\\Users\STaiwo\Desktop\My R code')
page = requests.get("https://www.flyingblue.com/earn-and-spend-
miles/airlines/partner/180/china-eastern.html", verify = False)
print(page.content) ### Collects HTML content of site 
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
print(soup.prettify()) ## Cleans up the content of the site 
for table in soup.findAll('tbody'):
print('Table')
list_of_rows = []
for row in table.findAll('tr')[1:]:
    list_of_cells = []
    for cell in row.findAll('td'):
        text = ((cell.text.replace('&nbsp;', '')))
        list_of_cells.append(text)
    list_of_rows.append(list_of_cells)
print(list_of_rows)
```

**The Result I'm currently getting:**
Table
[['First Class', 'F, U', '150%'], ['P', '125%'], ['Business Class', 'J, C, D, I', '125%'], ['Premium Economy Class', 'W', '110%'], ['Economy Class', 'Y, B', '100%'], ['E, H, M', '75%'], ['L, N, R, S, V, K', '50%'], ['T', '30%'], ['Not eligible for accrual', 'Z, Q, G', '0%']]
Table
[]
Table
[]
Table
[['Distance in miles: 6,482', 'Total'], ['Booking sub-class: 125%', '8,103'], ['8,103']]
Table
[['Distance in miles: 6,482', 'Total'], ['Booking sub-class: 125%', 'Elite bonus: 75%', '12,965'], ['8,103', '4,862']]
Table
[['Distance in miles: 6,482', 'Total'], ['Booking sub-class: 50%', '3,241'], ['3,241']]
Table
[['Distance in miles: 6,482', 'Total'], ['Booking sub-class: 50%', 'Elite bonus: N/A', '3,241'], ['3,241', '0']]

**The Result I want:**
Table
[['First Class', 'F, U', '150%'], ['P', '125%'], ['Business Class', 'J, C, D, I', '125%'], ['Premium Economy Class', 'W', '110%'], ['Economy Class', 'Y, B', '100%'], ['E, H, M', '75%'], ['L, N, R, S, V, K', '50%'], ['T', '30%'], ['Not eligible for accrual', 'Z, Q, G', '0%']]

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `[:1]` to `soup.findAll('tbody')` It will limit results to first table only.

Answer (score 0):

The page renders in French for me, so what you want looks like this in my browser.
[image: desired table]

Examining the HTML I see that several tables have the same `id`, namely `inlineTable`. To select the correct one, even if the publishers change the position of this table on the page, then it is necessary to be able to identify it in some other way. I notice that the heading 'Classe de cabine' is unique to this table and it's likely to be available as 'Cabin class' in the English version. Let's use that.

First, get all of the tables with that `id`. Look at the text of each table for 'Classe de cabine'. When you find that spit out it rows, except for the header row.

```
>>> import requests
>>> page = requests.get('https://www.flyingblue.com/earn-and-spend-miles/airlines/partner/180/china-eastern.html').text
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')
>>> required_tables = soup.select('#inlineTable')
>>> len(required_tables)
7
>>> for table in required_tables:
...     if 'Classe de cabine' in table.text:
...         rows = table.findAll('tr')
...         for row in rows[1:]:
...             row
...             
<tr class="table-highlite-light">
<td rowspan="2" width="33%">Première Classe</td>
<td width="33%">F, U</td>
<td width="33%">150 %</td>
</tr>
<tr class="table-highlite-light">
<td>P</td>
<td>125 %</td>
</tr>
<tr class="table-highlite-light">
<td>Classe Affaires</td>
<td>J, C, D, I</td>
<td>125 %</td>
</tr>
<tr class="table-highlite-light">
<td>Premium Economy Classe</td>
<td>W</td>
<td>110 %</td>
</tr>
<tr class="table-highlite-light">
<td rowspan="4">Classe Économique</td>
<td>Y, B</td>
<td>100 %</td>
</tr>
<tr class="table-highlite-light">
<td>E, H, M</td>
<td>75 %</td>
</tr>
<tr class="table-highlite-light">
<td>L, N, R, S, V, K</td>
<td>50 %</td>
</tr>
<tr class="table-highlite-light">
<td>T</td>
<td>30%</td>
</tr>
<tr class="table-highlite-light">
<td>Non éligible pour l’accumulation</td>
<td>Z, Q, G</td>
<td>0 %</td>
</tr>
```